# How can I split an osm file into separated files with poly files using osmosis?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I have got a country.osm file and I want to split it alongside of admin_level=8. I extracted previously ~3.000 poly files into a separated folder.
I have batch script, that split them, if I give the input and the poly:

```
osmosis --read-xml %1 enableDateParsing=no --bounding-polygon file=%2 completeWays=no completeRelations=no clipIncompleteEntities=true --write-xml file=clc_%2.osm
```

**The question:** Are there any way to do this parallel and the input file read just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You have to rework your script file. Add as many polygons as you want as in the example here: http://blog.geofabrik.de/?p=75

This will read the input file only once and output as many files as you polygons you specified.

Comment: Yes, I already found this site, but it didn't worked by this way. Then I changed my osmosis 0.41 to 0.39 and the problem solved.